# Json Schema conditional checking without hard coding

Tags: json, schema, monaco-editor

I am writing a schema for an editor for questionnaires. The schema defines how questions can be formatted. A user will write json that follows the schema, and that json will represent a questionnaire.

The schema will act as a set of rules for the questions, and the editor will use those rules to determine if the json can be accepted as a valid questionnaire.

Some questions will have a condition, like this:

```
            {
              "condition": "first_question",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "key": "second_question",
                  "type": "boolean",
                }
              ]
            }
```

That condition represents the key of another question.
How can I check that if there is a condition for a question (in this case "first_question"), that there is an object with that key somewhere else in the schema, without hard coding keys into the schema?

As a follow up, if this is possible, is there a way to see if that conditional key appears *before* the key that is dependent on it?